# Golang smart contract issue during invoking

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Facing an issue in golang smart contract, while invoking chaincode create function i am getting an error of argument.

Whenever I'm going to send a string of array as an argument in Chain-code function. I'm getting an issue.

here I'm attaching my function implementation.

```
func (m *MdmChaincode) CreateSeqMrNum(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, args []string) error {
    
 
    SeqId := args [0]
    SrNo := args [1]
    DocType := args [2]

    mtrSeqNo := &SeqMrNum{SeqId, SrNo, DocType}
    seqMrNumAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(mtrSeqNo)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to marshal the JSON.")
    }

    err = ctx.GetStub().PutState(SeqId, seqMrNumAsBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot add to World State: %s", err.Error())
    }
    return nil

}
```

> Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message: "Error managing parameter param0. Conversion error. Value 'M1001' not passed in expected format []string.

Facing an issue in golang smart contract, while invoking chaincode create function I am getting an error of argument.

Whenever I'm going to send a string of array as an argument in Chain-code function. I'm getting an issue.

here I'm attaching my function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your transaction function implementation is expecting the client to pass a single argument, which is a slice of strings. How well this is supported, I am not sure. If it is, I think the contract runtime will be expecting the client to format that single argument as a JSON array of strings.

It might be easier to accept each piece of information as a separate parameter:

```golang
func (m *MdmChaincode) CreateSeqMrNum(
    ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface,
    seqID string,
    srNo string,
    docType string
) error {
    ...
}
```

and then have your client submit a transaction with those three distinct arguments:

```golang
contract.Submit("CreateSeqMrNum", client.WithArguments(seqID, srNo, docType))
```

Alternatively, if you want the client to pass a JSON (or some other format) parameter containing all the required information, you could accept a single string parameter that you then explicitly deserialise within the smart contract.